# Python Signals between threads

Tags: python, signals

I created a UDP socket server

```
self.UDPServer = SocketServer.UDPServer( ( UDP_IP, UDP_PORT ), UDPServerHandler )        
self.server_thread = threading.Thread( target = self.UDPServer.serve_forever )
self.server_thread.setDaemon( True )        
self.server_thread.start()
```

And this is my UDP handler

```
class UDPServerHandler( SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler ):

    def handle( self ):
        recv = '';        
        try:
            ans = self.request[0]
            print "received" + ans
            if( ans ):
                #recv = self.checkMessage( recv + ans );
                print( ans )               
        except:
            pass;
```

My question is, how can I send the received data to an other thread? For example I have a GUI, and I want to display the received massage in a text box, or work on the received data etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach is to use the [Queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html) module.

Comment: Can you provide me an example, or a link to a tutorial, please?

Comment: If I have two classes they can share one queue?

Comment: @Kicsi: I already provided you a link that contains an example.